# Are copied spells cast from the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you copy [Increasing Confusion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Increasing%20Confusion) or any other "cast from the graveyard" spell with [Increasing Vengeance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Increasing%20Vengeance), does the copy act like it was cast from the graveyard? Or, since the copy technically was not cast from the graveyard, would it just have the normal effect?

Answer (score 12):

Your instincts are correct. Copies of spells are just placed on the stack, they are never **cast**.

> 706.10. To copy a spell or activated ability means to **put a copy of it on to the stack; a copy of a spell isn’t cast** and a copy of an activated ability isn’t activated.

Cards on the other hand, can be copied and cast. For example, if [Increasing Vengeance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Increasing%20Vengeance) was enchanted by [Spellweaver Volute](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spellweaver%20Volute), the copy of the card **would** be cast from a graveyard.

Comment: @darch, corrected. Used the wrong card in the example

Comment: Basically, the copy appears in whatever zone the card being copied was in.

Answer (score 3):

The *copy a spell* and *cast a spell* actions are distinct and unrelated. A spell created by [Increasing Vengeance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Increasing%20Vengeance) was created by a copy action, not by a cast action. If that spell was [Increasing Confusion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Increasing%20Confusion), its replacement effect doesn't come into effect since it wasn't cast (from the graveyard or otherwise). This is specifically covered by the rules.

> 706.10. To copy a spell or activated ability means to put a copy of it on to the stack; a copy of a spell isn’t cast [...]

Compare with [Spellweaver Volute](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spellweaver%20Volute), which copies cards you then cast (from the graveyard).

Comment: Adjusted as recommended.