# Are copied Flashback cards cast from the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are copied spells cast from the graveyard?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8923/are-copied-spells-cast-from-the-graveyard)

If a card like [Increasing Devotion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIncreasing%20Devotion%5d) is copied and its Flashback cost has been paid, does the copy count as being cast from a graveyard? So would you end up with double the tokens with your copied spell?

Comment: This is technically an [exact duplicate](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/revisions/8924/2) of this, and covers the special case of cards that can be copied and cast from the graveyard using something like Spellweavers Volute.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

A copy of a spell isn't cast. Therefore, the "if Increasing Devotion was cast from a graveyard" clause won't trigger.

Rules reference:

> 706.10. To copy a spell or activated ability means to put a copy of it onto the stack; **a copy of a spell isn't cast** and a copy of an activated ability isn't activated. A copy of a spell or ability copies both the characteristics of the spell or ability and all decisions made for it, including modes, targets, the value of X, and additional or alternative costs. (See rule 601, "Casting Spells.") Choices that are normally made on resolution are not copied. If an effect of the copy refers to objects used to pay its costs, it uses the objects used to pay the costs of the original spell or ability. A copy of a spell is owned by the player under whose control it was put on the stack. A copy of a spell or ability is controlled by the player under whose control it was put on the stack. A copy of a spell is itself a spell, even though it has no spell card associated with it. A copy of an ability is itself an ability.

Answer (score 0):

No. "Copy" and "cast" are two different Keyword Actions, and neither is defined in terms of the other. If a spell was copied, it wasn't cast.

> 706.10. To copy a spell or activated ability means to put a copy of it onto the stack; a copy of a spell isn’t cast and a copy of an activated ability isn’t activated. [...]

Note that some abilities (such as [Isochron Scepter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Isochron%20Scepter)'s) allow you to cast copies of cards, but that's not the case here since you're talking about a spell that was cast using flashback.